# Переопределение вывода (html-ки) плагина в своей теме Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Доброго дня, решил сверстать свою первую тему для wp, и сразу же столкнулся с проблемой переопределения вывода новостного плагина.
Скачал подходящий плагин новостей, но его стандартный вывод не подходит под мою верстку, поэтому подумал переопределить вывод плагина. Но не знаю как это сделать и где. Подскажите пожалуйста в каком направлении двигаться, думал что в теме создать файл functions.php и в нем переопределить вывод, но не могу понять что куда вставлять.

Comment: если самим плагином возможность изменения разметки новости не предусмотрена, то сама CMS в этом не поможет

Answer (score 1):

Если стили переопределить то просто через инструменты для разработчиков посмотреть какие классы там используются и перебить их в своем файле стилей. Если функционал то проще другой плагин найти.

Comment: Получается что такой возможности в wp нет? До этого верстал темы под subrion, там была возможность переопределять вывод для каждого плагина. т.е не css-ки править а переделывать варианты вывода самой структуры html